# How should I give label names to the model output with coreML convert

Tags: keras, coreml, coremltools

I have build a model using keras and I want to convert it to coreML using this function :

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
coreml_model.save(‘myModel’)
```

The output of my model is a 10 neurons layer to predict 10 classes. My issue is that I would like to give the label name associated with each neuron `classA`, `classB`, etc.

The doc shows a lot of parameters (https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.keras.convert.html) but I can't understand which one to use : `output_names`, `predicted_feature_name`, or `predicted_probabilities_output`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... I just did not read the doc properly.. I had to use the `class_labels` parameters.